# org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: Getter not found: &NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null

Tags: json, dart, list-comprehension, dart-null-safety

I'm working on a simple online dictionary mobile app. There were no errors until one-day I decided to search for the word "pick"
The app works on API provided by [DictionayAPI](https://dictionaryapi.dev/).
The API that gets called when I search for "pick" is [this](https://api.dictionaryapi.dev/api/v2/entries/en_US/hell).
I created few classes to store the data from the API, which goes like :

```
class Word {
  final String name;
  bool isFavourite;

  Word({required this.name, this.isFavourite = false});
}

class Phonetics {
  String text;
  String audio;

  Phonetics({required this.text, required this.audio});
}

class Meanings {
  Meanings({required this.partOfSpeech, required this.definitions});

  String partOfSpeech;
  List<Definitions> definitions;
}

class Definitions {
  Definitions(
      {required this.definition,
      required this.example,
      required this.synonyms,
      required this.antonyms});

  String definition;
  String example;
  List<Word>? synonyms;
  List<Word>? antonyms;
}


class DictData {
  Word word;
  Phonetics phonetics;
  String origin;
  List<Meanings> meanings;

  DictData(
      {required this.word,
      required this.phonetics,
      required this.origin,
      required this.meanings});
}
```

And I created a Future Function for it,
inside that future function, I created an instance of the class **DictData**
and when there is supposed to be a list, I used list comprehension like this;

```
property: [ for(int counter = 0; counter < (JSON_objectContainingList == null ? 1 : JSON_objectContainingList.length); counter++) JSON_objectContainingList[counter]]
```

the problem is it works partially, My actual program (function looks like this :

```
Future<DictData> dictionaryCall({required String userInputWord}) async {
  var url =
      Uri.https('api.dictionaryapi.dev', '/api/v2/entries/en/' + userInputWord);

  var response = await http.get(url);

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var dictResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);

    DictData object = DictData(
        word: Word(name: dictResponse[0]["word"]),
        phonetics: Phonetics(
            text: dictResponse[0]["phonetics"][0]["text"] as String,
            audio: dictResponse[0]["phonetics"][0]["audio"] as String),
        origin: dictResponse[0]["origin"] ?? "",
        meanings: [
          for (int mindex = 0;
              mindex <
                  (dictResponse[0]["meanings"] == null
                      ? 1
                      : dictResponse[0]["meanings"].length);
              mindex++)
            Meanings(
                partOfSpeech: dictResponse[0]["meanings"][mindex]
                    ["partOfSpeech"],
                definitions: [
                  for (int dindex = 0;
                      dindex <
                          (dictResponse[0]["meanings"][mindex]["definitions"] ==
                                  null
                              ? 1
                              : dictResponse[0]["meanings"][mindex]
                                      ["definitions"]
                                  .length);
                      dindex++)
                    Definitions(
                        definition: dictResponse[0]["meanings"][mindex]
                            ["definitions"][dindex]["definition"],
                        example: dictResponse[0]["meanings"][mindex]
                                ["definitions"][dindex]["example"] ??
                            "",
                        synonyms: [
                          for (int syndex = 0;
                              syndex <
                                  (dictResponse[0]["meanings"][mindex]
                                                  ["definitions"][dindex]
                                              ["synonyms"] ==
                                          null
                                      ? 1
                                      : dictResponse[0]["meanings"][mindex]
                                                  ["definitions"][dindex]
                                              ["synonyms"]
                                          .length);
                              syndex++)
                            Word(
                              name: dictResponse[0]["meanings"][mindex]
                                  ["definitions"][dindex]["synonyms"][syndex],
                            )
                        ],
                        antonyms: [
                          for (int aindex = 0;
                              aindex <
                                  (dictResponse[0]["meanings"][mindex]
                                                  ["definitions"][dindex]
                                              ["antonyms"] ==
                                          null
                                      ? 1
                                      : dictResponse[0]["meanings"][mindex]
                                                  ["definitions"][dindex]
                                              ["antonyms"]
                                          .length);
                              aindex++)
                            Word(
                              name: dictResponse[0]["meanings"][mindex]
                                  ["definitions"][dindex]["antonym"][aindex],
                            )
                        ])
                ])
        ]);
    return Future.value(object);
  } else {
    throw Exception("Something went wrong, please try again later");
  }
}
```

In the First List comprehension, there's an integer variable called "mindex" serving as the counter for that specific List, when I debugged it in VS Code, "mindex" does works.
Moving to the Second List Comprehension, There's another  integer variable called "dindex" which for no surprise works well there.
The problem is with the third List comprehension, there's an integer called "syndex", it says :

```
syndex
org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: Getter not found: 'syndex'.
syndex
^^^^^^
```

Then another error pops up after that on last (fourth list comprehension) inside

```
Word(
    name: dictResponse[0]["meanings"][mindex]
        ["definitions"][dindex]["antonym"][aindex],
)
```

which says

```
Exception has occurred.
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: [](0))
```

Answer (score -1):

This error occurs whenever you use something like this

```
data["fieldName"]
```

Here, if the **`data` is NULL**, then you'll get this type of error.

So, you have to use a null check, like this,

```
if(data!=null){
//DO Something
}
else{
print("data is NULL");
}
```

So, according to the second error, it seems that  three integers `mindex,dindex and aindex`. So, one of them would be equal to 0 at a some time, and you're getting the error one or more of the following fields are null,

```
meanings, definitions, antonym
```

So, you should do something like this,

```
(a[0]!=null && a[0]["field"]!=null && a[0]["field"][mindex]!=null]...) ?  //and so on
            Word(
            name: dictResponse[0]["meanings"][mindex]
                ["definitions"][dindex]["antonym"][aindex],
        ) : 
Word(//do something else);
```

Comment: This does not answer why the counter called `syndex`  throws error :
`org-dartlang-debug:synthetic_debug_expression:1:1: Error: Getter not found: 'syndex'.`
Also, the the API I'm calling is not null, if it's returns null, 
`
if (response.statusCode == 200) { }
`
shall handle it fairly well

Comment: It isn't the problem with the status code. It would be the issue with the response that you got. In response, I think you're receiving a null data somehow. 
I've edited the answer and added a bit more explanation. In short, you have to add null check.

Comment: There are 4 integers `mindex`, `dindex`, `syndex`, & `aindex`.
Among those, the integer `syndex` is not working, it says getter not found [and not `null`]